# How to parse xml with optional elements

Tags: c#, xml, postgresql, xslt, postgresql-9.1

SEPA ISO XML transactions file needs to be parsed into flat table  in Postgres 9.1+ in ASP:NET 4.6 MVC controller.

I tried code below but this produces wrong result:

```
endaaa            tasusumma  orderinr
XX00221059842412     150.00  PV04131
XX00221059842412       0.38  PV04131
```

Since there is no EndToEnd in second row there should be null or empty text in second row orderinr column:

```
endaaa            tasusumma  orderinr
XX00221059842412     150.00  PV04131
XX00221059842412       0.38  null
```

How to fix this ?

Parsing can done in other ways e.q. using xslt stylesheet for tranformation or in client side ASP.NET 4.6 MVC if this is more reasonable.

```
create temp table t(x xml, nsa text[][]) on commit drop;
insert into t values(
'<?xml version=''1.0'' encoding=''UTF-8''?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Acct>
        <Id>
          <IBAN>XX00221059842412</IBAN>
        </Id>
      </Acct>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">150.00</Amt>
        <NtryDtls>
          <TxDtls>
            <Refs>
              <EndToEndId>PV04131</EndToEndId>
            </Refs>
          </TxDtls>
        </NtryDtls>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">0.38</Amt>
        <NtryDtls>
          <TxDtls>
            <Refs>
              <AcctSvcrRef>2016080100178214-2</AcctSvcrRef>
            </Refs>
          </TxDtls>
        </NtryDtls>
      </Ntry>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
', ARRAY[ARRAY['ns','urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02']]);

SELECT 
unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Acct/ns:Id/ns:IBAN/text()', x,nsa))::text AS endaaa,
unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry/ns:Amt/text()', x,nsa))::text::numeric AS tasusumma
 , unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry/ns:NtryDtls/ns:TxDtls/ns:Refs/ns:EndToEndId/text()', x,nsa))::text AS orderinr
FROM t;
```

**Update**

Using code from Hannes answer returns empty rows in Postgres 9.1 How to make it work in 9.1 ?

Posted also in pgsql.general mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract all ns:Ntry elements first, and then get the amount and EndToEndId for each of them:

```
SELECT 
    endaaa,
    (xpath('ns:Amt/text()', x,nsa))[1]::text::numeric AS tasusumma,
    (xpath('ns:NtryDtls/ns:TxDtls/ns:Refs/ns:EndToEndId/text()', x,nsa))[1] AS orderinr

FROM (
    SELECT (xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Acct/ns:Id/ns:IBAN/text()', x,nsa))[1] as endaaa,
    unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry', x,nsa)) as x, nsa
    FROM t
) Ntry
```

Comment: In 9.1 it returns two empty rows. How to make it work in `"PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit"` ? In 9.5 it works.

Comment: I've verified that the query works in "PostgreSQL 9.1.23 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit". It seems you will have to upgrade to at least 9.1.15 to get an xpath() namespace handling error fixed.

Comment: Thank you. How to add IBAN column to result table also?  It has same value for all rows. I modified question with new testcase. How to get endaa? column in result set. Server runs in Debian Squeeze which is unsupported. Don't know how to upgrade.

Comment: Answer updated to include IBAN. This will only work if there is exactly one single "ns:Stmt" entry in the XML! Else you will have to build a third query level, first selecting the ns:Stmt entries, second the IBAN and Ntry from them and third amount and EndToEndId.

Comment: Regarding upgrading, please check https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/ for instructions on how to use the PostgreSQL APT repository. I'm not really a Debian expert, but as far as I see, there should 9.1.23 be available for Squeezy as well.