# How to parse ISO bank statement

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing, postgresql-9.1

I'm looking for a way to create Postgres 9.1+ table from SEPA ISO XML bank statement, single row for every transaction as described in [How to parse xml with optional elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888739/how-to-parse-xml-with-optional-elements)

Code below returns null values How to fix this so that amounts 1.34 and 5.56 are returned?

```
create temp table t(x xml, nsa text[][]) on commit drop;
insert into t values(
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <Stmt>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">1.34</Amt>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">5.56</Amt>
      </Ntry>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document> '::xml,
    ARRAY[ARRAY['ns','urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02']]);
    SELECT 
    (xpath('Amt/text()', x,nsa))[1]::text::numeric AS tasusumma
    FROM (
        SELECT unnest(xpath('/ns:Document/ns:BkToCstmrStmt/ns:Stmt/ns:Ntry', x,nsa)) as x,
        nsa
        FROM t
    ) Ntry
```

It must work starting at  PostgreSQL 9.1.2.

Comment: Could it be your XPath is simply not finding anything? Try `//Amt/text()`.

Comment: It works in 9.1. In Postgres 11 it requires namespace specification for every element in xpath. How to make it work in every postgres version?

Comment: @Andrus If PostgreSQL version 9.1.2 and 11 have different namespaces you will need to register those namespaces like you did with `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02`